# Checking for nulls in distinct

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq

I have tried a bunch of different ways to do this but every time I try this it throws a null reference exception.

I am trying to filter the values in a field to have a list of the unique values inside that field. It works on fields with no missing values but when i use it on fields that i know to have null values it throws an exception so im assuming that is what i should be filtering for.

The original way i was doing this was just looping through the values and checking if the list of unique values contained the value yet but this was taking a long time and i wanted to harness the power of Linq

```
List<Graphic> ReturnedGraphics = e.FeatureSet.Features as List<Graphic>;


IEnumerable<string> ValueSet = (
                                 from g in e.FeatureSet.Features
                                 where !uniquevalues.Contains((g.Attributes[_selectedField] == null ? "blank" : g.Attributes[_selectedField].ToString()))
                                 select g.Attributes[_selectedField] == null ? "blank" : g.Attributes[_selectedField].ToString()
                               ) as IEnumerable<string>;

if (ValueSet.Any())
{
    uniquevalues.AddRange(ValueSet);
}
```

I should also add that the reason im adding a range to the list is because there are 5000 values coming in from the server which has a limiter on values to return, however it works for this and shouldn't have an effect on what im trying to do here.

Comment: That code is insanely difficult to read.  You gain nothing by stuffing everything into a three line LINQ query.

Comment: Side-note: don't use `ValueSet.Count() > 0` to check whether or not the sequence contains elements but `ValueSet.Any()`. Your approach executes the whole query.

Comment: Also, that many ToString() calls are definitely a code smell.

Comment: What are all those comments in the code you posted?

Comment: .ToString() can never return a null value. The object itself may be null but that's causing your NullReferenceException

Comment: Tim's right that `ValueSet.Count` is potentially slow (though likely not significantly here since AddRange will outweigh it), but you don't need to check for emptyness at all!

Comment: And you probably don't need to check whether uniquevalues already contains the value: if ValueSet truly is a set (`ISet<string>` eg `HashSet<string>`) duplicate values will never be added.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne: AddRange won't _outweigh it_ since AddRange won't know how large the sequence is (because it is not a `ICollection<T>`).

Comment: @spender All the comments are the different methods i am using to try and filter unique values. however one thing to keep in mind is that each feature set is only a 5000 batch of the entire set that is coming in and needs to be compared to the master list of unique values. I'm working with a server hat has a limiter of how many items can be sent, but can be overridden if you only ask for the objectID. I want to try and stay away from tinkering with the server so Im doing it this way for now.

Comment: Why does it need to be compared to a master list? Why not choose a collection that only allows unique values then just add everything you encounter (as suggested by Eamon above)? HashSet would be a good candidate. Iterating a list-like structure to check for duplication will be increasingly costly with more items. Adding to a HashSet is constant time regardless of # of items.

Comment: First time i've heard of a hashset

Comment: ...But Im going to have to sort it. thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `.ToString()` null values. Looks like you might be trying to. Candidates for null include `lstbxFields.SelectedValue`, `g.Attributes[someVal]`

How about rationalizing your code so that the errors are easier to trap and you're not repeating yourself all over the place?

```
var selVal = lstbxFields.SelectedValue;
if(selVal == null)
{
    //act on this
    return; //or throw
}
var selectedValue = selVal.ToString();

var query=
    e.FeatureSet.Features
        .Select(feature => feature.Attributes[selectedValue])
        .Select(attr => attr == null 
                        ? "blank" 
                        : attr.ToString())
        .Where(attrVal => !uniquevalues.Contains(attrVal));
```

Comment: the [field].ToString() was what was throwing the errors. 

So, in some cases i may be trying to use this on over 200000 features in batches of 5000, and what im trying to do is optimize the process. I've set it up to warn the user if the process is trying to accomplish this for more than 100000 items but I was wondering if how im approaching this is the optimal way.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You simply want a unique collection of the values of all feature attributes with name x?

Comment: Yes, but each set is only a subset of the master set coming in. I'm doing it this way for now till i can figure out how to override the server into attaching the values for the field. I've posted another comment in my question.

Comment: ...and im tweaking the batch size in comparison to the client side processing time. The server that sends the data is a bit of a black box with some properties that i can adjust but for the most part im building around the limitations of the server.
And what im basically asking , because im new to Linq, is what the optimal way to filter out the unique items from a batch.

Answer (score -1):

Your data model is almost certainly "wrong" in the sense that it's very error prone and hard to work with.  You should not be converting everything to `string` but working on the strongly typed objects directly.  Doing so will likely fix this bug automatically as it's very likely the NullReferenceException is being thrown when you attempt to ToString a null value.

Not only is it much safer to work on the typed objects, it's also much faster and will result in shorter code.